# Can you help me get this grid layout working? Equal column length, but one column can be however long it wants

Tags: css, css-grid

Could some one help me design this layout with CSS Grid?

The red box should in theory be able to be however long it wants. The green boxes should maintain stacked on eachother.

The red box and green box should be the same width, so 1/2.

[image: Example]

Ive tried to play around with grids and rows and its such a headache. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It would be good to at least post your basic HTML structure and the CSS you've tried.

Comment: You probably also need to offer more information, to save people posting red herring answers. It's easy with Grid to set the red bos to the same height as the two green ones, but it sounds like you don't necessarily want that al the time. What kinds of variables exist here?

Comment: Hey sorry, so the red one doesnt need to be the height of the two green boxes. It could be as long as it wants, and the green boxes will always remain stacked ontop of eachother, taking up the second half. They would maintain their heights regardless of how long the red box gets

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to tell the red box to span three grid rows.

```css
.layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr)); /* two equal columns */
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.layout>* {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 3px solid green;
  color: green;
}

.layout>*:nth-child(1) {
  border: 3px solid red;
  color: red;
  grid-row: 1 / span 3; /* first box spans three rows */
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div>1<br><br>1<br><br>1<br><br>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Or perhaps a more robust but slightly more complicated solution would be to use a grid with a single row, just to manage the columns, then using flexbox within each column.

```css
.layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr)); /* two equal columns */
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.layout>* {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  gap: 1rem;
}
.layout>*>* {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 3px solid green;
  color: green;
}

.layout>*:nth-child(1)>* {
  border: 3px solid red;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div>
    <div>1<br><br>1<br><br>1<br><br>1</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated my answer to add a hybrid option using grid and flex together ... this would be better if you have a varying number of boxes in the right column and/or if the content in the left column could be either shorter or longer than the content in the right column.

Comment: Okay, I am happy to help you further, but only once you add these additional stipulations into your question. Please edit your question to make it as descriptive and precise as possible. Why, you may ask? Because Stack Overflow is not just about helping you, it's about building a library of helpful information which can help others in future. That's why we insist that people take time to make their questions self-contained and as clear as possible. It also means you'll get quicker and more accurate answers.